# Error while running supertest: Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?

Tags: sequelize.js

Project have sequelize.authenticate call just after Sequelize initialization. When running basic tests I am getting "Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?   Attempted to log "Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result"." error as it has to wait for running select 1+1.

```
    const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConfig.DB, dbConfig.USER, dbConfig.PASSWORD, {  host: dbConfig.HOST,
  dialect: dbConfig.dialect,
  operatorsAliases: false,
  timezone: '+05:30',

  pool: {
    max: dbConfig.pool.max,
    min: dbConfig.pool.min,
    acquire: dbConfig.pool.acquire,
    idle: dbConfig.pool.idle,
  },
});

sequelize
    .authenticate()
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
    });
```

Test

```
const supertest = require("supertest");
const app = require('./app') 
const request = supertest(app);


describe("Test the root path", () => {
  test("It should response the GET method", async () => {
    const response = await request.get("/");
      expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
  });
});
```

How should it be handled?

Comment: Hi Aman, have you found the solution to this one?